# how to use htaccess to respond from folder or file with same name?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have this on my /html directory:

```
.htaccess
info/
info/public.php 
info.php
```

htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

One app call to
`info/public?format=json`

Another app call to
`info?format=json`

I can't figure out how to make both request get response since second request is returning 404.
Any idea?

Comment: Do you want `info?format=json` to be handled internally as `info.php?format=json` ?

Comment: Yes.  ```info.php?format=json``` response is not equal to ```info/public.php?format=json``` response.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you to replace your rule with this code in site root .htaccess:

```bash
DirectorySlash Off
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Here:

- `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f`: Checks for the presence of corresponding `.php` file as the value of `$1`. Your condition `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` was only checking if the request is not for a file.
- `Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews -Indexes`: Turns off options `MultiViews` (content negotiation) and `Indexes` (disables directory listing)
- `DirectorySlash Off`: avoids trailing `/` being added to a directory since you have `info/` as subdirectory and `info.php` also exists.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I'm still getting 404 on info?format=json

Comment: What is your `DocumentRoot` setting in Apache config?

Comment: I have tested this code on my local Apache and everything seems to be working fine. You can try to replace `RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f` with `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f`